# Avoid to copy some content while scraping through pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have some difficulties in saving the results that I am scraping.
Please refer to this code (this code was slightly changed for my specific case):

```
import bs4, requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import time

headline=[]
corpus=[]
dates=[]
tag=[]  

start=1
url="https://www.imolaoggi.it/category/cron/"

while True:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')


    headlines=soup.find_all('h3')
    corpora=soup.find_all('p') 
    dates=soup.find_all('time', attrs={'class':'entry-date published updated'}) 
    tags=soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'cat-links'})
    for t in headlines:
        headline.append(t.text)
    
    for s in corpora:
        corpus.append(s.text)
        
    for d in date:
        dates.append(d.text)
    
    for c in tags:
        tag.append(c.text)
    if soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'page-numbers'}):
      url = f"https://www.imolaoggi.it/category/cron/page/{page}"
      page +=1
    else:
      break
```

Create dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, headline, tag, corpus)), 
               columns =['Date', 'Headlines', 'Tags', 'Corpus'])
```

I would like to save all the pages from this link. The code works, but it seems that it writes everytime (i.e. every page) two identical sentences for the corpus:

[image]

I think this is happening because of the tag I chosen:

```
corpora=soup.find_all('p')
```

This causes a misalignment in rows in my dataframe, as data are saved in lists and corpus starts being correctly scraped later, if compared to others.

I hope you cab help to understand how to fix it.

Comment: i feel you are the same user which asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64601712/limited-number-of-scraped-data) but from different account?

Comment: I followed that question and answer. That question is what I have been referring to in my question ("this code was slightly changed for my specific case"), but I did not find the link. Thanks a lot Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but your selectors were off, and you mis-naned some of your variables.

I would use css selectors like this:

```
eadline=[]
corpus=[]
date_list=[]
tag_list=[]  


headlines=soup.select('h3.entry-title')
corpora=soup.select('div.entry-meta + p') 
dates=soup.select('div.entry-meta  span.posted-on')
tags=soup.select('span.cat-links')

for t in headlines:
    headline.append(t.text)

for s in corpora:
        corpus.append(s.text.strip())

for d in dates:
        date_list.append(d.text)

for c in tags:
        tag_list.append(c.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date_list, headline, tag_list, corpus)), 
               columns =['Date', 'Headlines', 'Tags', 'Corpus']) 
df
```

Output:

```
    Date    Headlines   Tags    Corpus
0   30 Ottobre 2020     Roma: con spranga di ferro danneggia 50 auto i...   CRONACA, NEWS   Notte di vandalismi a Colli Albani dove un uom...
1   30 Ottobre 2020\n30 Ottobre 2020    Aggressione con machete: grave un 28enne, arre...   CRONACA, NEWS   Roma - Ha impugnato il suo machete e lo ha agi...
2   30 Ottobre 2020\n30 Ottobre 2020    Deep State e globalismo, Mons. Viganò scrive a...   CRONACA, NEWS   LETTERA APERTA\r\nAL PRESIDENTE DEGLI STATI UN...
3   30 Ottobre 2020     Meluzzi e Scandurra: “Sacrificare libertà per ...   CRONACA, NEWS   "Sacrificare la libertà per la sicurezza è un ...
```

Comment: thank you @Jack Fleeting, also for suggesting me the use of css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


def main(req, num):
    r = req.get("https://www.imolaoggi.it/category/cron/page/{}/".format(num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    goal = [(x.time.text, x.h3.a.text, x.select_one("span.cat-links").get_text(strip=True), x.p.get_text(strip=True))
            for x in soup.select("div.entry-content")]
    return goal


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        fs = [executor.submit(main, req, num) for num in range(1, 2937)]
        allin = []
        for f in fs:
            allin.extend(f.result())
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            allin, columns=["Date", "Title", "Tags", "Content"])
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```